# What is the alternative for slimmer in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been using slimmer in python 2 but now I'm switching to Python3. I am not able to find alternative to slimmer in Python3. Can anyone suggest any alternative which can be used in Python3? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slimmer is no longer maintained, as stated by the author on the [Project's page](https://github.com/peterbe/slimmer), so it is very unlikely that it gets ported to Python 3 one day.

The author recommends using other projects (he mentions [UGLIFY-JS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) or [CSSMIN](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssmin)) that are not Python based (most "uglyfiers" are written in JS).

That makes it likely that, to use them from Python code, you will have to use a `subprocess.Popen()` call to their executable. You can create a wrapper function around this call to create a kind of Python binding.

Comment: Thanks for the help.